# How convert Json array to vis.dataset

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, chap-links-library

I am wring a website using Node.Js.
I got data from calling some API and returns to me JSON array in this format:

```
[{ '2015-04-08T17:12:05+00:00': 103.7 },{ '2015-04-08T17:13:05+00:00': 109.5 },{ '2015-04-08T17:14:05+00:00': 106 },{ '2015-04-08T17:15:05+00:00': 112.6 }]
```

So I want to use `vis.js` library to display this data like this:

[vis example](http://visjs.org/examples/graph2d/01_basic.html)

Please correct me if I am wrong. I think `vis.js` only accepts dataset in this format:

```
[{x: '2014-06-11', y: 10},{x: '2014-06-12', y: 25},{x: '2014-06-13', y: 30},{x: '2014-06-14', y: 10}]
```

1. converting json array format.
2. directly feeding the raw data to vis.js.

Don't know how to do it. 
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will permute your array to make it match your specs :

```js
var dataBefore = [{ '2015-04-08T17:12:05+00:00': 103.7 },{ '2015-04-08T17:13:05+00:00': 109.5 },{ '2015-04-08T17:14:05+00:00': 106 },{ '2015-04-08T17:15:05+00:00': 112.6 }];

var dataAfter = [];

for(var i = 0; i < dataBefore.length; i++) {
  var item = dataBefore[i];
  for(date in item) {
    dataAfter.push({x: date, y: item[date]});
  }
}

console.log(dataAfter);


//added below for display the output
$(".results").append(JSON.stringify(dataAfter));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">
</div>
```

Comment: A small addition: `var cleanDate = date.slice(0,10);
    dataAfter.push({x: cleanDate, y: item[date]});` to output the date format requested.